# Multiple TFS server for the same project

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, git-tfs

For the same project I want to use 2 TFS server, because I have 2 groups of developers and they can only access their own TFS and I can access both.

This is very easy to do with git. Take a look at my .git/config file. This project uses both github and bitbucket for remote.

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:company/project-app.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "origin-bitbucket"]
        url = git@bitbucket.org:company/project-app.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin-bitbucket/*
[branch "bitbucket-master"]
        remote = origin-bitbucket
        merge = refs/heads/bitbucket-master
```

Now, 2 sets of developers work on  both bitbucket and github. I merge their change and push them to both servers.

I have a business reason for this.

I am wondering if it is possible with TFS or not.

BTW, I would rather have 2 TFS servers, but 1 TFS and 1 git server is also acceptable.

Comment: Why do you want to have two TFS servers? TFS is designed with this in mind: If you need total isolation between two sets of artifacts (builds, work items, source code, etc), use two Team Project Collections on one server. There's something fishy going on here, though... if everything should be isolated, why do you want to duplicate code between the two? Instead of duplicating code, there are several solutions you could use that make a ton more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to sync 2 TFSVC server!

If you want to sync 1 TFS with 1 git, perhaps you could using :

- git-tf if you have no branches
- git-tfs if your main server is TFS and that you will push after to your git repository (you could use branches).

But with the two solutions, it will be a pain in the ass!

The better solution is to convince your colleagues to use TFS2013 Git repositories. There is a lot to win here! And you could migrate your sources with git-tfs...

Answer (score 1):

With TFS 2013 you can choose between classical TFS Version Control (TFVC) and Git for the source control backend.

If you like the git workflow you're using, just setup 2 TFS Servers and choose to use the Git backend.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2013/11/13/git-for-tfs-2013.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, I do not control one of the TFS servers, and it is running TFVC.

Comment: You can use git-tf to integrate Git and TFVC.